# How do I scan a git repository for possible CVE-2014-9390 malicious commits?

Tags: git, cve-2014-9390

Using stock git porcelain and plumbing, how does one search all reachable commits for instances of possibly malicious additions to `.GiT`, `.gIt`, and so on?

For context, see

- [[ANNOUNCE] Git v2.2.1 (and updates to older maintenance tracks)](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1853266)
- [Git 1.8.5.6, 1.9.5, 2.0.5, 2.1.4 and 2.2.1 and thanking friends in Mercurial land](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2014/12/git-1856-195-205-214-and-221-and.html)
- [Vulnerability announced: update your Git clients](https://github.com/blog/1938-git-client-vulnerability-announced)
- https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-9390

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the first link you've given (Git v2.2.1 Release Notes / Fixes since v2.2):

> "git fsck" notices a tree object that records such a path that can
>      be confused with ".git"

So, just update to the latest git, run `git fsck`, and you are done.